# API to get Tor SSL certificates

Tags: connection, protocol, ssl, certificate, tls

Some onion websites, like facebook, have TLS implemented on top of Tor. Is it possible to fetch the certificates and TLS versions of these connections using something like torpy?

Answer (score 0):

cURL https://curl.haxx.se + OpenSSL CLI, you need nothing more to perform your task

Comment: As a suggestion, you could perhaps add more details about how you could fetch the certificates and TLS versions to better support your answer.

Comment: It's in the cURL library docs, nothing beyond it... If there's anything in particular you want to see - just drop me a line!